# Using Sequelize.Instance with Sequelize v5 & Typescript

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

In most guides, chats, tutorial etc... the recommended way to type Sequelize models is to use the following code:

```
export interface IUserInstance extends Sequelize.Instance<IUserAttributes>, IUserAttributes {
  prototype: {
    verifyPassword: (password: string) => boolean;
  };
}
```

the key part here is `Sequelize.Instance<`, in Sequelize v5+ you see the error:

```
Namespace '".../node_modules/sequelize/types/index"' has no exported member 'Instance'.
```

I have looked around but have not come across solution.

** Looking at this guide, section "Usage of sequelize.define"
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/typescript

There does NOT seem to be a clear way of working with associations in using define and typescript.

Any help / advice would be appreciated.

References:

- https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/35013
- https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9760#issuecomment-472905585
- https://vivacitylabs.com/setup-typescript-sequelize/

Regards,
Emir

Answer (score 2):

I searched a lot for a solution to this problem, and got it working with the following:

```
import sequelizeInstance from '..';
import { Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

const config = {
  tableName: 'User',
  sequelize: sequelizeInstance,
};

class User extends Model {
  id!: number;
  firstName!: string;
  lastName!: string;
  /* some other properties*/

  verifyPassword: (password: string) => boolean;

  public readonly createdAt!: Date;
  public readonly updatedAt!: Date;
}
User.init(
  {
    id: {
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    firstName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    }
  },
  config,
);

User.prototype.verifyPassword = function(password: string) {
  /* code here ... */
};

export default User;
```

Comment: I am using Sequelize with Feathers.js, so I need to use the sequelize.define(... approach. 

The example given here: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/typescript, shows your method and works well (I assume), when you are working directly with classes.

Comment: @Aston Could you give the `sequelizeInstance` contents?

Comment: @Laiso It is basically `new Sequelize(url, config)` but here is my complete file I use https://gist.github.com/eshton/03ec6cf7b14b8e74843ccea7c5ff4815